# Suddenly appengine devmode task requests to 0.0.0.0 refused

Tags: java, google-app-engine

**Update**: When I disable GWT for my project, this problem goes away!

I've been happily using task queues in appengine for several months, and dev mode testing has been great on my Mac OS X machine.

Today, it all came crashing down.

```
[ERROR] Job CleanupQueue.task1 threw an unhandled Exception: 
com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$ApplicationException: ApplicationError: 2: Received exception executing http method POST against URL http://0.0.0.0:8888/tasks/cleanup: Connection to http://0.0.0.0:8888 refused
    at com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.dev.LocalURLFetchService.fetch(LocalURLFetchService.java:381)
    at com.google.appengine.api.taskqueue.dev.LocalTaskQueue$UrlFetchServiceLocalTaskQueueCallback.execute(LocalTaskQueue.java:480)
    at com.google.appengine.api.taskqueue.dev.UrlFetchJob.execute(UrlFetchJob.java:77)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:203)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:520)
[ERROR] Job (CleanupQueue.task1 threw an exception.
org.quartz.SchedulerException: Job threw an unhandled exception. [See nested exception: com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$ApplicationException: ApplicationError: 2: Received exception executing http method POST against URL http://0.0.0.0:8888/tasks/cleanup: Connection to http://0.0.0.0:8888 refused]
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:214)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:520)
* Nested Exception (Underlying Cause) ---------------
com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$ApplicationException: ApplicationError: 2: Received exception executing http method POST against URL http://0.0.0.0:8888/tasks/cleanup: Connection to http://0.0.0.0:8888 refused
    at com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.dev.LocalURLFetchService.fetch(LocalURLFetchService.java:381)
    at com.google.appengine.api.taskqueue.dev.LocalTaskQueue$UrlFetchServiceLocalTaskQueueCallback.execute(LocalTaskQueue.java:480)
    at com.google.appengine.api.taskqueue.dev.UrlFetchJob.execute(UrlFetchJob.java:77)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:203)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:520)
```

I haven't changed anything in my project, and reverting to a previously-working version does n't help.  0.0.0.0 is an ip coming internally from the dev server - all of my other references use localhost or 127.0.0.1. I *did* recently install some OS updates from Apple, but I would have sworn that dev mode has worked between then and now.

Where can I start looking for the cause?  Thanks for any ideas - I'm stumped!

Note: the same code and setup on my windows machines works great.

Note 2: starting from scratch with the GAE java sdk 1.5.5, I made the simplest-possible taskqueue sample app and got the same connection refused messages.

## Extra Info

ifconfig:

```
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 16384
    inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 
    inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1 
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000 
gif0: flags=8010<POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST> mtu 1280
stf0: flags=0<> mtu 1280
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether c8:2a:14:0d:d8:e8 
    inet 192.168.2.1 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.2.255
    media: autoselect (none)
    status: inactive
fw0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 4078
    lladdr 70:cd:60:ff:fe:6a:28:ae 
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
en1: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 78:ca:39:b4:c3:8a 
    inet6 fe80::7aca:39ff:feb4:c38a%en1 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x6 
    inet 192.168.2.3 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.2.255
    media: autoselect
    status: active
```

Comment: @NickJohnson I hate to lean on you directly, but you're my only link to the appengine team - any ideas? This has been an all-but-show-stopper for a WEEK!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've worked around the problem.

The class that launches a GWT&GAE project from eclipse is `com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher`.  This class hard-codes `0.0.0.0` as the IP to bind to, which according to the comments should cause it to listen on all interfaces.

I just copied the code from this class into an `AppEngineLauncherHack` class, which hard-codes a more specific IP (in my case, `192.168.0.12`), and changed my run configuration to use this class instead.

I haven't figured out what the ultimate conflict was.  I don't know why 0.0.0.0 used to work, but doesn't anymore.  Unsatisfying, and definitely a kluge - if this starts happening on other machines, we'll have to make a new `AELauncherHack` class for every computer!  But at least now we can get back to business.

Thanks for the help everyone - I'm sorry I could only award the bounty to one person!

Answer (score 3):

I haven't seen this issue (running the Python SDK, and tasks are working locally in our MacOS X environments), but have you tried the switch to listen on all IPs?

Passing
--address 0.0.0.0
in the extra flags in the launcher should bind to all and allow you to use localhost or your actual IP.  Of course, that *shouldn't* be required, but it's something you can try as an experiment.

Are you passing an explicit target to the task?  Is your app running on the non-default port of 8888?

What's the output of ifconfig look like?  Are there any virtual adapters or other network devices that have changed around the time this went haywire?

Comment: On OS X you can check the port using a terminal and type: _netstat | grep 8888_. If nothing is running on that port use _netstat_ and see if you can find your port. More information using _man netstat_.

Comment: Here's the weirdest part: using a browser to fetch stuff (and post stuff!) to 0.0.0.0:8888 works _fine_.  It's specifically the task queue driver that's throwing this error about being refused.  I've tried passing 0.0.0.0 explicitly, and also tried running on another specific IP, but this task-driving code must be hard-coded to hit 0.0.0.0.

Comment: I added the output if ifconfig to the OP. `netstat` didn't have any 8888s listed, even as firefox was pulling stuff off of localhost:8888.  Maybe local connections show up as things like `rileysmac.49171`? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You should not use 0.0.0.0 as connection target. 0.0.0.0 has a special meaning: It refers to All IP addresses (imagine it to be *.*.*.*). That is often used when binding a listening socket to all available interfaces.

So even if the listening socket is bind to 0.0.0.0 you should not use that same ip to connect to it. Often you can connect to loopback IP 127.0.0.1 or to your active public ip (check ipconfig in win or ifconfig in linux).

Different applications and operating systems may handle 0.0.0.0 differently as connection target. This might explain why it did work in your Firefox.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions about how to get appengine to use a different connection target for the task queue?  This is not something I have configured.

Comment: You could try to use --address=... when starting devserver. You probably have something broken in your operating system networking settings that made it stop working.

Comment: Unfortunately that switch doesn't help - the devserver is still trying to reach 0.0.0.0:8888, and the connection is refused.

Answer (score 1):

0.0.0.0 is a special kind of address. In this context it means "all IP addresses(IPv4) on the local machine". So, if your appengine is listening on port 8888, this means it has bind to all available ip addresses. So from your configuration, it should be accessible on localhost(*127.0.0.1:8888*), *192.168.2.1:8888* and *192.168.2.3:8888*. You can verify that trying something like:

```
telnet 192.168.2.1 8888
```

So first of all, your should not pass that around as IP address.

It will be interesting to check, if you have access to: http://localhost:8888/_ah/admin/
when the server is running.

From version >=2.0.1  of the appengine, the default behavior of devmode, is that it will bind only to localhost. In order to bind to or all available IPv4 addresses (a.k.a. 0.0.0.0) you (or if it's stared automatically by program with some predefined configuration e.g. Eclipse) have to specify **-bindAddress 0.0.0.0**. Maybe it will be useful if you check your Eclipse Run configuration - Arguments - Program arguments if you run it from Eclipse, which lead us to the next question. How do you start the app engine? There are two options and note that

"when you start the development server from within Eclipse using the Google Plugin for Eclipse, the server uses the **port 8888 by default**. When you start the server using the dev_appserver command, it **uses the port 8080 by default**."

You mentioned that you have done an upgrade of your OS. I have found this [issue](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4712) connected with JDK update, but the discussed version is **Java SE 6 Update 4**. Still I think it's worth mentioning it here. Also we should assume, that after the update, there was **no firewall upgrade** which made it autostart, right?

I would also suggest checking your configuration in ant-macros.xml and see what values are there:

```
<attribute name="port" default="8080" description="The port the server starts on"/>
<attribute name="address" default="localhost" description="The interface the server binds to"/>
```

Comment: Yes, finally - writeup coming.  Thanks for the help!