# Install previous version of GPE?

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, gwt, eclipse-plugin, google-eclipse-plugin

I want to roll back my Google Plugin for Eclipse to a previous version.  How can I accomplish that?

Comment: Why do you need to downgrade the plugin?  You can easily downgrade the SDKs, but the plugin is only available from the Eclipse update site, which only has the latest version.

Comment: I've been struggling with an obscure problem with my development environment and can't figure it out.  It survives clean re-installs of eclipse and my entire operating system.  The only thing I can't revert is the GPE... it's the last stone to turn.

Comment: Link to obscure problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7972282/suddenly-appengine-devmode-task-requests-to-0-0-0-0-refused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have a copy of the older version, you can't roll back. You can definitely get old versions of GWT, but they don't keep around old versions of GPE.

Answer (score 3):

Use `Help>About>Installation Details>Installation History` to see your past list of installed configurations.  You should be able to select one and revert to that configuration.

**EDIT**: update from comments

While eclipse keeps around the past configurations it may need to go to p2 repositories on the internet to download the older artifacts (and that can trip up some configuration reverts).

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like Eclipse doesn't keep hold of the old files it'll need to revert - I get the errors `No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle.e36.feature,1.5.3.r36v201108301710
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.e36.feature,2.4.0.r36v201108301710
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.feature,1.3.2.20110218-0812`

Comment: Does your `Preferences>Install/Updates>Available Update Sites` still contain the Eclipse release repo (like http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo)?

Comment: Yes, it does. The setup on this machine has been complicated, though, and I've re-installed eclipse a few times.  I wouldn't be surprised if some files it normally keeps around are gone now.  Blegh.